# How to pass a keyword to Git on commit

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have done a CICD job on Gitlab where commit of files in the repository triggers the job, builds the file and publish the files to a server. It was working fine but now my job should identify the server too while commit because the environment now have 4 servers pointing 4 different regions. How can a developer pass some keyword(even a 2 letter word should work) while commit other than commit message which I can retrieve in the Gitlab CICD job.

I have researched on the various environment variables that Gitlab have but I none of them suits my requirement. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

- you can use tags, and trigger the build job only on tags with a specific format
- you can create a pipeline which expects variables, and trigger that pipeline with a direct http call (e.g : `curl` or a specific script)

---

Further details :

- the OP does not have the lattitude to change the structure of the git repository
- the repository contains a directory, with a list of files

  - each of these file describes a specific product
  - each of these files is a yaml file
  - depending on the product, the file needs to be pushed, when modified, to one or several of 4 potential target servers

My suggestion is : add something which descibes what files need to be pushed to what server.

for example : add a `# @companycicd : publish srv1 srv3` comment in the file if it needs to be pushed to srv1 and srv3

and update the CICD job so that it gets the list of target servers for each file from this specific coomment line.

Comment: I have already tried the second option and is working but I would like to have the job run when commit happens and hence cant expect variables from user. 

Does the first option means that I need to tag each commit and with that I get an identifier from the tag message?

Comment: Can you explain what are the 4 regions, and how a commit can be related to a region and ignored in another ?

Comment: Sorry for the mess I created here. I have a single repo of few products file which i need to publish to four different catalogs in IBM API Connect. Few commits(few products) needs to go to catalog1 whereas others might need to publish to catalog2 or 3 or 4.

Comment: How are the catalogs separated in your git repo ? one file per catalog ? one directory per catalog ?

Comment: catalogs are not seperated in git repo...we have a single repo for that...all product files will be present in this repo..hence i am in need of a keyword from commiting user which catalog this product should be published to...sometimes some product needs to be published to multiple catalogs too...

Comment: Yes, you have a single repo, but inside that repo, how are the files organised ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191161/discussion-between-legec-and-abhi88).